# MinGW 4.6.2 std::atomic pointer

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++11, mingw

I'm using MinGW 4.6.2 on Windows XP and I've run into some strange behavior with std::atomic.
The situation is as follows:

- Thread A creates an **std::atomic** variable (with **T*** as template parameter).
- Thread B modifies it.
- Thread A waits for the modification then reads the variable.

The end result is that the value read by thread A is **not** the one set by thread B.

If I remove the std::atomic (that is saves the variable as a pointer) it works as expected. And more interestingly, if I set the template parameter to *unsigned long* and cast the pointer to and from *T** it works as expected.

I'm using the assignment operator to set the value and the load member to get the value.

Am I missing how the std::atomic with T* as parameter should work or is this broken behavior?

EDIT

Some code

```
    #include <boost/thread.hpp>
    #include <atomic>

    using namespace std;

    void* vptr;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> aui;
    std::atomic<void*> aptr;

    void foo()
    {
        vptr = (void*) 0x123;
        aui = (unsigned int) 0x123;
        aptr = (void*) 0x123;
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        boost::thread threadA;

        vptr = nullptr;
        aui = 0;
        aptr = nullptr;

        threadA = boost::thread(foo);
        threadA.join();

        cout << vptr << " " << (void*)aui.load() << " " << aptr.load();

        return 0;
    }
```

Output is: 0x123 0x123 0x41d028

Comment: Don't describe code, post it.

Comment: Don't cast pointers to `unsigned long`. Use `std::uintptr_t`, that's what it's there for.

Comment: "... if I set the template parameter to unsigned long and cast the pointer to and from T* it works as expected."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your problem with MinGW 4.6.1 (and found it fixed in 4.7.0). If you're unable to move to a newer MinGW that has fixed the problem, you should be able to patch the `lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/atomic_0.h` header's definition of the `_ATOMIC_STORE_` macro like so (assuming that the headers in 4.6.2 are similar enough to 4.6.1):

```
#if 0 /* disable the original broken macro */
#define _ATOMIC_STORE_(__a, __n, __x)                      \
  ({typedef __typeof__(_ATOMIC_MEMBER_) __i_type;                          \
    __i_type* __p = &_ATOMIC_MEMBER_;                      \
    __typeof__(__n) __w = (__n);                           \
    __atomic_flag_base* __g = __atomic_flag_for_address(__p);          \
    __atomic_flag_wait_explicit(__g, __x);                 \
    *__p = __w;                                \
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit(__g, __x);                      \
    __w; })
#else
#define _ATOMIC_STORE_(__a, __n, __x)                      \
  ({typedef __typeof__(_ATOMIC_MEMBER_) __i_type;                          \
    __i_type* __pxx = &_ATOMIC_MEMBER_;                    \
    __typeof__(__n) __w = (__n);                           \
    __atomic_flag_base* __g = __atomic_flag_for_address(__pxx);        \
    __atomic_flag_wait_explicit(__g, __x);                 \
    *__pxx = __w;                                  \
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit(__g, __x);                      \
    __w; })
#endif
```

The problem seems to be the local variable in the macro named `__p`, which apparently causes confusion when the macro is invoked with a variable also named `__p` for the macro parameter `__n`. When `__n` gets expanded to `__p`, instead of accessing the variable the invoker 'passed' in, the expanded macro accesses the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

This might be http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51811 - which is fixed in GCC 4.7

Can you show the code that causes the problem?

Comment: Only assigning the atomic to a value using the assignment operator.